# Property 'nome' does not exist on type 'AppComponent', but the property is correctly declared in component.ts

Tags: angular

I'm trying to print a variable using string interpolation in angular, i declare it in my .ts file as you can see here:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
})

export class HomeComponent {

nome = 'nome'

}
```

And I try to print it in this way:

```
<form>
    <mat-form-field>
        <label>{{nome}}</label>
        <input matInput type="text" name="nome">     
    <mat-form-field />
    <mat-form-field >
        <label>Email</label>
        <input matInput type="email" name="email">     
    <mat-form-field />
 <form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for asking the obvious but do you get an error? and if so, what does the error say?

I have created a quick angular application and replicated what you are trying to do, and everything works as expected.

Regards

Comment: Property 'nome' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'. this is the error

Comment: The reason you are getting this error is because you declared the variable 'nome' on the HomeComponent and AppComponent does not know about it.

I would suggest you move the form markup to the HomeComponent and then declare the variable as an input on the home component.

Then add `<app-home [nome]="nome"></app-home>` where app-home is the selector name.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).